# Installing Acquia BLT on an existing site

Tags: composer, 9, acquia-cloud

We have a working Drupal 9 installation (running within [Docksal](https://docksal.io)), which has pretty much the whole install living in `docroot/` except for the `config/` directory, which is a sibling of `docroot/`.  This application is fairly plain-vanilla--no custom modules, just some well-known contrib modules and normal config.  I will refer to it herein as the "working app."

In order to get this application onto [Acquia Cloud](https://cloud.acquia.com) and set up our CI/CD we hope to use their [BLT utility](https://docs.acquia.com/blt/).

We have tried several approaches to get BLT working with this application:

1. Create a [Docksal Drupal 9 BLT boilerplate application](https://docs.docksal.io/tools/acquia-blt/) and attempt to use
   `composer install` to get the same set of modules as the working app, and
   then import the working app's configuration with `fin drush cim`.
2. Create a [Drupal 9 BLT
   boilerplate application](https://docs.docksal.io/tools/acquia-blt/) and hand-edit `composer.lock` with selections
   from the working app's `composer.lock` file, run `composer install`, and
   then import the working app's configuration using `fin drush cim`.
3. Install BLT within the
   working app as described here:
   https://docs.acquia.com/blt/install/adding-to-project/.

Approaches 1 & 2 did not work because of incompatibilities between the BLT boilerplate app's composer configuration requirements (`minimum-stability dev` and `prefer-stable true`) and those configurations in the `composer.json` file of the working app.  There were also version incompatibilities between the contrib modules in the working app and those which the BLT boilerplate app wanted to install.   Hand editing the `composer.json` file also proved equally fruitless.

Using approach 3 we got as far as installing BLT in that the `blt/` directory and associated files are now present, but `blt doctor` complains of a missing `docroot/docroot` directory.  Looking at the differences in the filesystem layout between the BLT boilerplate app and the working app made it seem like it might be worth trying to move `vendor/`, `sites/`, `composer.json` and `composer.lock` up one level from within `docroot/` such that those two directories and two files are now siblings of `docroot/` and seeing if that satisfies `blt doctor`.  Doing this of course breaks the application and makes composer unhappy.  I have tried the following:

1. Deleting everything in `vendor/` and running `composer install`
2. Running `composer dump-autoload`
3. Hand-editing `docroot/autoload.php` looking for and
   attempting to edit incorrect filesystem locations within the
   relocated `vendor/` directory

As you can imagine, none of the above have worked and we are just about at the end of our patience with this endeavor.

I have a few general questions:

1. Are any of the three approaches above likely to result in a successful BLT install?
2. With regard to approach 3, is there a generally accepted method of moving either `vendor/`, `composer.*` and/or the `sites/` directory as described above?

Thank you in advance for any general or specific help you can offer.

Comment: Maybe start with setting up a fresh site with BLT and simply require any additional contrib module with Composer to it, and then try to import the existing config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Composerize Drupal looked like it would be the ideal solution for our problem--it would nuke our composer.* files, put directories where best practices dictated, and re-composerize the application.  Sadly, it's just too far out of date (it hasn't been updated in 2 years) and I ran into several problems installing it either globally on my machine or within docksal.

The solution that worked was Approach #1 in my question above (also what [leymannx](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/15055/leymannx) had suggested).  That said, it certainly was not as simple as `cp -R working-app/config/* blt/config/` followed by `fin drush -y cim`.

We had to do the following, in this order:

1. Within the blt drupal run `fin drush cex` to generate baseline
   config export files.
2. Within the working app run `fin drush cget system.site uuid` and then set that as the site uuid in the blt app
   `fin drush set system.site uuid xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx`
3. Within the blt app, run
   `composer require` for all the contrib modules in the working app.
4. Hand copy the custom theme from the working app to blt's
   `docroot/themes/custom` Hand-merge both apps'
   `config/default/core.extensions.yml` files, with specific importance
   on making sure to override blt's `minimal` install profile with the
   working app's `standard` install profile and to make sure the custom
   theme from the working app was present in the blt
   `core.extensions.yml`.
5. Once that was done, `fin drush -y cim` worked
   (as did `fin drush uli` just to make sure), and `fin blt doctor`
   reported no issues.

Answer (score 0):

You have two distinct problems here:

1. "Composerizing" your codebase
2. Installing BLT

The latter should be pretty painless once you've got the former (theoretically more painful) out of the way.

Fortunately, the [Composerize Drupal](https://github.com/grasmash/composerize-drupal) plugin should get you most if not all of the way there. From the description of your project, you'll want to run this in the root folder (the one containing config/ and docroot/). You don't need to move anything out of the docroot/ folder yourself, anything that needs to be updated will be.

Once that process is complete, run database updates (contrib modules may have been updated to more recent versions), clear cache, verify the site is working, and commit the changes.

At this point you have the structure BLT is expecting, so following the installation instructions again (link in your third approach) should work out a bit better.